# What is this part (label is 23LCVB I/P JWD 1336, 8-DIP package)?

Tags: integrated-circuit, identification, dip

I found this part in a box with random parts. Mostly they were voltage regulators, opamps and transistors (both BJT and FET).

[image: 23LCVB I/P JWD 1336, 8-DIL package]

The closest match I found was [this SPI SRAM](http://pdf.datasheetarchive.com/indexerfiles/Datasheets-AS1/DSAASSA0007373.pdf), but the part number didn’t match completely.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's definitely a [Microchip 23LCV1024](http://www.microchip.com/wwwproducts/Devices.aspx?product=23LCV1024). Section 6.1 of the datasheet shows the markings on the top line of the DIL8 as "23LCVB".

Comment: Meh I now see the legend on the left side of the page, which says that the other labels are quite irrelevant.. Gotta learn to first read *closely* then ask.